# creating indicator variables if a time is within certain intervals

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a column of times that have been entered as raw text. An example is below (code for data input at the bottom of the post):

```
#>   id    time
#> 1 NA    <NA>
#> 2  1 7:50 pm
#> 3  2 7:20 pm
#> 4  3 3:20 pm
```

I would like to add indicator variables, that for example, indicate if the time is:

- after 7pm
- between 7pm and 7.30pm

So my desired output would look like this:

```
#>   id    time before_1930 between_1900_1930
#> 1 NA    <NA>          NA                NA
#> 2  1 7:50 pm           0                 0
#> 3  2 7:20 pm           1                 1
#> 4  3 3:20 pm           1                 0
```

So far, I have tried reading in the times with `parse_date_time`, but this adds on a date:

```
library(lubridate)
df <- df %>% mutate(time = lubridate::parse_date_time(time, '%I:%M %p'))
df
```

```
#>   id                time
#> 1 NA                <NA>
#> 2  1 0000-01-01 19:50:00
#> 3  2 0000-01-01 19:20:00
#> 4  3 0000-01-01 15:20:00
```

Is there an easy way to work directly with the hours and minutes, and then create the dummy variables I mentioned?

### Code for data input

```
df <- data.frame(
          id = c(NA, 1, 2, 3),
        time = c(NA, "7:50 pm", "7:20 pm", "3:20 pm")
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
data.frame(
   id = c(NA, 1, 2, 3),
   time = c(NA, "7:50 pm", "7:20 pm", "3:20 pm")
 ) %>% 
   mutate(real_time = lubridate::parse_date_time(time, '%I:%M %p'),
          is_before = case_when(
            hour(real_time) < 19  ~ "Before 19",
            hour(real_time) == 19 & minute(real_time) < 30 ~ "19:00 - 19:30",
            T ~ "After 19:30"
          ))
  id    time           real_time     is_before
1 NA    <NA>                <NA>   After 19:30
2  1 7:50 pm 0000-01-01 19:50:00   After 19:30
3  2 7:20 pm 0000-01-01 19:20:00 19:00 - 19:30
4  3 3:20 pm 0000-01-01 15:20:00     Before 19
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to deal with it as a date/time, use your output from `parse_date_time` to calculate the number of hours since midnight on `0000-01-01`.

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(NA, 1, 2, 3),
  time = c(NA, "7:50 pm", "7:20 pm", "3:20 pm")
)

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df <- df %>% mutate(time = lubridate::parse_date_time(time, '%I:%M %p'), 
                    time = difftime(time, 
                                    as.POSIXct("0000-01-01", tz = "UTC"), 
                                    units = "hours"), 
                    before_1930 = as.numeric(time < 19.5),
                    between_1900_1930 = as.numeric(time > 19 & time < 19.5))
df
```